# Plupload conflicts with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, html, upload, plupload

Basically, front-end of plupload works well without bootstrap. But when there is bootstrap, it does not. Is there any idea to solve this issue?
Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/vucuong12/4qs6kzfm/ (add bootstrap to see that front-end will not work well)

```
<script src="http://www.plupload.com/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

1.Without bootstrap
[image: Without bootstrap]

2.With boostrap

[image: With bootstrap]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to re-arrange script order as below, noted that jQuery -> Bootstrap -> jQuery UI. Tested and worked well on my machine.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.plupload.com/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgithub.com/moxiecode/plupload/master/js/plupload.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgithub.com/moxiecode/plupload/master/js/jquery.ui.plupload/jquery.ui.plupload.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thks, this is exactly solution that I found

Comment: Yep, that worked for me too. Strange, I don't need it in this exact order for any other script in any of my websites -- only for this "plupload" product.